# virtual filesystems appear to be limited on win32 build of Midnight Commander

Tags: windows-7, ssh, filesystems, zip, midnight-commander

I installed Midnight Commander 4.8.7 on my windows machine at work.
2 of the features that I would love to use are the virtual filesystems for zip files and ssh.
But the only virtual filesystem that appears to be available is FTP.

Do I need extra plugins, or is this functionality simply lacking in the windows port?